# Simple Android / Firebase orderByChild / equalTo

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This I suspect is easy, but I can't get it to work as I want. I'm referencing a database ref with my query information for my Firebase database. The code below works fine, but I can't hard code in Match_01 (this was purely done to get the code working).

```
String getArgument = getArguments().getString("matchid");
            final DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Matches").child("Match_01");
```

What I need to do is use the matchID thats been passed to the fragment and use equalTo instead of referencing the final child node.

```
final DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Matches").orderByChild("gameID").equalTo(getArgument);
```

But this doesn't work, I can't swap out the last child reference for the orderByChild reference.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming from your question that the `Matches` node's children have the id you want to reference dynamically as a key.

Then, you need `orderByKey` instead of `orderByChild`. This should work:

```
final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Matches");
Query q=ref.orderByKey().equalTo(getArgument);
```

When using `orderByChild`, the query will match nodes against this node's attributes. In other words, your attempt would work on a collection with the following structure:

```
- Matches
  - $key
    - gameID: "Match_01"
```

Comment: It keeps throwing an error; Error:(70, 33) error: incompatible types: Query cannot be converted to DatabaseReference

Comment: try it now, I have edited the answer VonD to fix the error

Comment: That works great, my bad though, I call a transaction block, its why I was trying to chain together my DB ref by passing the query in on the same line;                 final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Matches");
                Query q=ref.orderByChild("gameID").equalTo(getArgument);

                ref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {